# Jest reports that a method from a enzyme shallowed component has not been called in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

So I have a generic class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class CompTest extends Component {
  someFunc() {}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.someFunc();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hey</div>;
  }
}
```

and I want to check that `someFunc` gets called at least once (inside `componentDidMount`)

```
describe("<CompTest /> componendDidMount", () => {
  it("should call someFun()", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<CompTest />);
    const instance = instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, "someFun");

    expect(instance.someFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

however I am getting:
`Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.`

According to enzyme v3 docs: `As of Enzyme v3, the shallow API does call React lifecycle methods such as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.`

What is wrong with my test? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(enzyme maintainer here)

The issue is that you're spying on the `someFunc` method after the original has already been passed into the render tree. Try this:

```
describe("<CompTest /> componendDidMount", () => {
  it("should call someFun()", () => {
    jest.spyOn(CompTest.prototype, 'someFunc');
    const wrapper = shallow(<CompTest />);

    expect(wrapper.instance().someFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am getting `ReferenceError: someFunc is not defined` when I try to do the spy 
`jest.spyOn(CompTest.prototype, someFunc)`

Comment: My bad, typo, missing ' ' in `someFunc`.
I am getting  `Cannot spy the someFunc  property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Comment: Are you sure you used `someFunc() {}` and not `someFunc = () => {}`? Never use arrow functions in class fields; use field-bound or constructor-bound instance methods, and then this spying method should work.

Additionally, the code you provided wasn't wrapped in any HOCs - that matters *very much*, so please update your OP with *unsimplified* code if so.